# Issues with props in a function component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

---

### Edit:

Now I get this error:

```
Property 'addColumns' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<{ myProps: any; }>'.ts(2339)
```

With this code:

```
Const Djitsheet: React.FC<{ myProps }> = (props) => {  
 console.log('', props) 
  let dataToPass: Array<any> 
   let addColumnsToPass: boolean = props.addColumns  
 let addRowsToPass: boolean = props.addRows
```

---

### Original:

I am attempting to convert a JSX React function component into a TSX one. This is for an internship, and it's my first attempt at such. I just need to get it started and then I will know where to go from there...

I am getting this error in VS Code with my TS React FC...

```
Type '{ (props: myProps): JSX.Element; defaultProps: Partial<{ props: myProps; }>; propTypes: React.WeakValidationMap<{ props: myProps; }>; }' is not assignable to type 'FC<{ props: myProps; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<{ props: myProps; }>' has no properties in common with type 'myProps'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my code.

```
interface myProps {
  id?: string
  size?: Array<number>
  data?: Array<any>
  headers?: Array<any>
  addColumns?: boolean
  addRows?: boolean
  readonly?: boolean
  snapToData?: boolean
}

const Djitsheet: React.FC<{ props: myProps }> = (props: myProps) => {

return <h1>Hello, from TSX</h1>
}

Djitsheet.defaultProps = {
  id: `my-sheet`,
  size: [4, 4],
  data: undefined,
  headers: [],
  addColumns: true,
  addRows: true,
  readonly: false,
  snapToData: false
}

Djitsheet.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.array,
  data: PropTypes.array,
  headers: PropTypes.array,
  addColumns: PropTypes.bool,
  addRows: PropTypes.bool,
  readonly: PropTypes.bool,
  snapToData: PropTypes.bool
}
```

I also get an error with the id prop in VS code that says:

```
Type '{ id: string; size: number[]; data: undefined; headers: undefined[]; addColumns: boolean; addRows: boolean; readonly: boolean; snapToData: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ props: myProps; }>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Partial<{ props: myProps; }>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: ```const Djitsheet: React.FC< myProps > = props => <h1>Hello, from TSX</h1>;```

Comment: Thank you, now I get this error:

`Property 'addColumns' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<{ myProps: any; }>'.ts(2339)`

With this code:

`Const Djitsheet: React.FC<{ myProps }> = (props) => {
  console.log('', props)
  let dataToPass: Array<any>

  let addColumnsToPass: boolean = props.addColumns
  let addRowsToPass: boolean = props.addRows`

Comment: I don't know how to format it better, will put it at the bottom of my original question

Comment: 1. Remove propTypes and defProps.

Comment: 2. Pass Interface without curly brackets. FC<myProps>

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Do you know if StoryBook will still be able to display props and default props without the propTypes and defProps though?

Comment: I don’t know. Try google `reactjs typescript storybook`. Or try to find package that transform Interface to propTypes.

Comment: @RickGove I put this code into a sandbox and can't reproduce the error. What are you doing differently from me? https://codesandbox.io/s/interfaces-and-props-pt827?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pass the `interface` to the declared `Functional Component` avoid passing it as a nested object.

Let's look closely at your "edit" version:

```js
// Const Djitsheet: React.FC<{ myProps }> = (props) => {

// pass "interface" the same way you pass "type"
Const Djitsheet: React.FC<myProps> = (props) => {
  console.log('', props) 
  let dataToPass: Array<any>;
  let addColumnsToPass: boolean = props.addColumns;
  let addRowsToPass: boolean = props.addRows;
  // ...
}
```